# Pontryagin square on $Y\times S^1$ where $Y$ is three-dimensional

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Let $Y$ be an oriented manifold of dimension three, and let $X=Y\times S^1$. We have

$$H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)=H^2(Y,\mathbb{Z}_2)\oplus H^1(Y,\mathbb{Z}_2).$$

Pick an element $m\oplus n\in H^2(Y,\mathbb{Z}_2)\oplus H^1(Y,\mathbb{Z}_2)$, and consider $\mathfrak{P}(m\oplus n)$, where $\mathfrak{P}$ is the Pontryagin square operation. When evaluated on the fundamental class $[X]$, it is an integer modulo 4, and I believe it is even

$$[X]\frown\mathfrak{P}(m\oplus n) =2k_Y(m,n)$$

where $k_Y(m,n)$ is defined modulo 2. I'd like to know more concrete explicit expression of $k_Y$.

(I think that it's of the form

$$k_Y(m,n)=([Y]\frown(m\smile n)) + \mathfrak{Q}_Y(n)$$

where $\mathfrak{Q}(n)$ is a quadratic form on $H^1(Y,\mathbb{Z}_2)$. If it's true, is there a more explicit expression for $\mathfrak{Q}_Y(n)$? The only thing I can think of is $[Y]\frown(n\smile\beta(n))$, where $\beta$ is the Bockstein. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think $[X] \frown \mathfrak{P}(m \oplus n) = 2\langle m \cdot n + n^3, [Y] \rangle$.

The class $m \oplus n$ is better thought of as $m \otimes 1 + n \otimes x$ under the Kunneth decomposition, where $x \in H^1(S^1;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is the nontrivial element. Then the quadratic property of $\mathfrak{P}$ and naturality gives
$$\mathfrak{P}(m \otimes 1 + n \otimes x) = \mathfrak{P}(m) \otimes 1 + \mathfrak{P}(n \otimes x) + 2(m \smile n \otimes x).$$

Firstly, $\mathfrak{P}(m) = 0$ as $Y$ is 3-dimensional.

Secondly, the fact that the suspension of the Pontrjagin square is the Postnikov square (and that the Postnikov square is not universally trivial, which bizarrely I can't find a reference for) means that
$$\mathfrak{P}(n \otimes x) = \bar{\mathfrak{P}}(n) = 2 n^3.$$

Remark: In an earlier version of this answer I had consulted

```
Nakaoka, Minoru
Note on cohomological operations. J. Inst. Polytech.
Osaka City Univ. Ser. A. Math. 4, (1953). 51–58.
```

which has the formula
$$\mathfrak{P}(n \otimes x) = \mathfrak{P}(n) \otimes \mathfrak{P}(x) + \bar{\mathfrak{P}}(n) \otimes \beta(Sq_2(x)) + \beta(Sq_2(n)) \otimes \bar{\mathfrak{P}}(n)$$
where $\bar{\mathfrak{P}}(-)$ is the Postnikov square (i.e. the operation given on cochains by $u \mapsto u \cup \delta u$), and $\beta$ is the Bockstein to $\mathbb{Z}/4$-cohomology. Each of $\mathfrak{P}(x)$ and $\bar{\mathfrak{P}}(x)$ must be trivial by degree reasons. If one interprets $Sq_2(x)$ literally it also ought to be zero, but this is apparently wrong and it ought to be interpreted as $1$.

Comment: Thanks; where can I have a look at the list of $H^i(K(\mathbb{Z}/2,1);\mathbb{Z}/4)$ and $H^i(K(\mathbb{Z},1);\mathbb{Z}/4)$?

Comment: Also, I'm a bit confused. Take $Y=\mathbb{RP}^3$, and consider a flat $SO(3)$ bundle over $Y\times S^1$, such that the holonomy $a$ around the generator of $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^3)$ and the holonomy $b$ around $S^1$ are given by $a=diag(-1,-1,1)$ and $b=diag(-1,1,-1)$ respectively. This bundle has $p_1=0$, and $w_2=\alpha^2+\alpha x$ where $\alpha$ is the generator of $H^1(\mathbb{RP}^3,\mathbb{Z}/2)$. Then $\mathfrak{P}(w_2)=\alpha^3 x$  according to your formula, but there's a general formula saying $p_1=\mathfrak{P}(w_2)$ mod 4, i.i.r.c. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: You probably didn't, and I probably did. Let me think about it.

Comment: I had been led astray by a strange formula. I think its right now (and fits with your example).

Comment: Thanks, but $\mathfrak{P}(n\otimes x)=2n^3$ doesn't seem to satisfy $\mathfrak{P}((n+n')\otimes x)=\mathfrak{P}(n\otimes x)+\mathfrak{P}(n'\otimes x)$ as I don't see $n^2 n'+ n' n^2$ to vanish in general...

Comment: $n^2n' +n (n')^2 = Sq^1(n n')$ and $Sq^1 : H^2(Y;\mathbb{Z}/2) \to H^3(Y;\mathbb{Z}/3)$ is given by cup product with the first Wu class $v_1$ (by definition), which is equal to the first Stiefel--Whitney class $w_1$, and vanishes as $Y$ is orientable.

Comment: No, cupping with $v_1$ only agrees with $Sq^1$ when it lands in the top degree, in this case 3 (this is the definition of $v_1$).

Comment: Thanks, I erased the question because I thought I should study this basic piece of algebraic topology first...Somehow there are many places on the internet where the cupping with $v_k$ equals $Sq^k$ even when it doesn't land in the top degree, like in Wikipedia:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel-Whitney_class#Wu_classes or nLab: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Wu+class . Doing the computation in $\mathbb{RP}^n$ it's clear it only works when the product lands in the top degree. Hmm ...

Comment: Of course I shouldn't have trusted what's available on the internet written by anonymous persons! Thank you very much, Oscar, for helping me. (The original question which I erased out of shame was why we don't have $n^2=Sq^1 n=v_1 n=0$. )